# How to Highlight Row Based on Maximum Value in Column (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a range of data from rows 1 to 10. And have different values in the columns A to G.

How can I highlight a row based on the highest value in column C?

Comment: first result if you search [`conditional formatting excel 2010`](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2010/using-conditional-formatting/1/) from Google. Use the formula suggested by Scott and if it works please consider marking it as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional Formatting with the formula:

```
=$C1=MAX($C:$C)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. Works great. How would I modify this to only apply this rule to a section of rows? When I change the applies to entry to =$A$1:$G$6 the format doesn't work..

Comment: @Luke You would need to change the formula to the same range: `=$C1=MAX($C$1:$C$6)`